# Powershell Script - Application Services Status Report email - need to highlight in red if service is stopped

Tags: powershell

I have a script that imports a csv file of six different servers to check the status of services for a particular application and emails a report each morning with service status (i.e. Running or Stopped).  Here is the script.  How would I highlight in red, the word "Stopped", for status in the email?

```
$CSVData = import-csv "C:\Scripts\Service.csv"
$Servernames = $CSVData.Servername | sort -unique
$output = @()

#$Cred = Get-Credential

foreach ($Server in $Servernames) {

$Services = $CSVData | Where {$_.Servername -eq $Server} | Select service
foreach ($Service in $Services) {
    write-host $Server
    $Serv = $Service.Service
    #$ServStat = Get-WMIObject -computer $server -credential $cred -Query "Select * From Win32_Service WHERE Name Like '$Serv'" | select displayname, state
    $ServStat = Get-WMIObject -Computer $Server -Query "Select * From Win32_Service WHERE DisplayName Like '$Serv'" | select displayname, state
    $Info = New-object -Typename PSObject
    $Info | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Hostname" -value $Server
    $Info | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "ServiceName" -value $ServStat.displayname
    $Info | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "ServiceStatus" -value $ServStat.state
    $Output +=$Info
}
}

# $Output | export-csv "C:\Scripts\Result.csv" -notype

$style = "<style>BODY{font-family: Arial; font-size: 10pt;}"
$style = $style + "TABLE{border: 1px solid black; border-collapse: collapse;}"
$style = $style + "TH{border: 1px solid black; background: #dddddd; padding: 5px; }"
$style = $style + "TD{border: 1px solid black; padding: 5px; }"
$style = $style + "</style>"


$mail = @{
    from       = "Application Name@company.org"
    to         = "Name@company.org"
    subject    = "Application Services Status Report - $(get-date -format MM-dd-yyyy)"
    body       = $Output | ConvertTo-Html -Head $style | Out-String
    bodyashtml = $true
    smtpserver = "[smtp server name]"
    port       = 25
}
Send-MailMessage @mail
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no idea if this will work, but it looks like you are doing HTML in the email, and I'm guessing the word "Stopped" is in the body.  So, what happens if you replace

```
body       = $Output | ConvertTo-Html -Head $style | Out-String
```

with

```
body       = $Output | ConvertTo-Html -Head $style -replace 'Stopped', '<p style="color:#FF0000";>Stopped</p>' | Out-String
```

?

Sorry, if this doesn't work, just my wild shot in the dark.

**EDIT:**

I'm not an HTML person, so I did a little more checking and maybe span style instead of p style is what we want.

```
body       = $Output | ConvertTo-Html -Head $style -replace 'Stopped', '<span style="color:red">Stopped</span>' | Out-String
```

**EDIT#2**

Just ran an experiment and this seemed to fix the PowerShell side of the problem.

```
body       = ($Output | ConvertTo-Html -Head $style) -replace 'Stopped', '<span style="color:red">Stopped</span>' | Out-String
```

Comment: Thanks.  I tried both the p style and span, but receive the error:  "ConvertTo-Html : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'replace'.
At line:36 char:56"

Comment: Paul, interesting.  That sounds like we need to replace the text some other way.  It doesn't yet say my idea of swapping out the text with HTML's span style is a failure, it just says I failed to work out the PowerShell side of the equation.

Comment: Paul, I do NOT think my second edit is allowing the $Output text to make through.  It stopped the error you reported, but something else seems wrong.  You can give it a try, but I'm going to try to figure what I'm seeing.

Comment: Thanks Darin.  Your second edit actually works.  I really appreciate your help resolving my issue.

Comment: You are welcome!  The problem I was having turned out that I'm not creating the content correctly in $Output and ConvertTo-Html didn't like it.  So couldn't prove on my end that it would work.  But very glad it worked on your end!

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way of doing it using a [Regex.Replace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.replace?view=net-6.0#system-text-regularexpressions-regex-replace(system-string-system-string-system-text-regularexpressions-matchevaluator)) with *script block* to add colors to the **ServiceStatus** column. I have hardcoded the CSV since we don't know how it actually looks.

The current code will generate a `test.html` file on your current location, this should be changed for your *send mail logic*.

```
$output = @'
Hostname,ServiceName,ServiceStatus
Server01,SomeService,Stopped
Server02,SomeService,Started
Server03,SomeService,Started
Server04,SomeService,Stopped
Server05,SomeService,Stopped
'@ | ConvertFrom-Csv

$style = @'
<style>
BODY {
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 10pt;
}
TABLE {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
TH {
  border: 1px solid black;
  background: #dddddd;
  padding: 5px;
}
TD {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 5px;
}
.ok {
  background-color: #C6EFCE;
  color: #006100;
  font-weight: bold;
}
.warning {
  background-color: #ffc7ce;
  color: #9c0006;
  font-weight: bold;
}
</style>
'@

$html = $output | ConvertTo-Html -Head $style -PreContent '<h1>Some Report</h1>'
[regex]::Replace($html, '<td>(Stopped|Started)</td>', {
    param($s)
    switch($s.Groups[1].Value) {
        Started { "<td class=ok>$_</td>" }
        Stopped { "<td class=warning>$_</td>" }
    }
}) | Out-File ./test.html

Invoke-Item ./test.html
```

You can run the snippet below to see how it looks.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
  <style>
    BODY {
      font-family: Arial;
      font-size: 10pt;
    }
    
    TABLE {
      border: 1px solid black;
      border-collapse: collapse;
    }
    
    TH {
      border: 1px solid black;
      background: #dddddd;
      padding: 5px;
    }
    
    TD {
      border: 1px solid black;
      padding: 5px;
    }
    
    .ok {
      background-color: #C6EFCE;
      color: #006100;
      font-weight: bold;
    }
    
    .warning {
      background-color: #ffc7ce;
      color: #9c0006;
      font-weight: bold;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Some Report</h1>
  <table>
    <colgroup>
      <col/>
      <col/>
      <col/>
    </colgroup>
    <tr>
      <th>Hostname</th>
      <th>ServiceName</th>
      <th>ServiceStatus</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Server01</td>
      <td>SomeService</td>
      <td class=warning>Stopped</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Server02</td>
      <td>SomeService</td>
      <td class=ok>Started</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Server03</td>
      <td>SomeService</td>
      <td class=ok>Started</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Server04</td>
      <td>SomeService</td>
      <td class=warning>Stopped</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Server05</td>
      <td>SomeService</td>
      <td class=warning>Stopped</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This looks really good too.  Thanks.